# What does char* mean?

Tags: loops, pointers, char

```c
int main() {

    int a, b;
    char* represent[10] = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
    scanf("%d\n%d", &a, &b);
    for(int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
        
        if(i > 9) {
            if(i % 2 == 0)
                printf("even\n");
            else printf("odd\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("%s\n", represent[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In this code, why do I need to write char* represent[10] and why just char represent[10] won't do it?

Answer (score 0):

Because char represent[10] is one char array, but you have several."one", "
Two", etc so char * represent[10] is a array of char pointer arrays. Each element of array might be a pointer to char array.

Comment: Got it, that's helpful.

Comment: Great, good luck